# How do I apply custom fragment shader to raster tile on MapBox GL JS?

Tags: shader, raster, mapbox-gl-js

I have png data tiles like dem and I want to display it on Mapbox GL JS through my custom fragment shader.
I cannot find the way to use custom shader for 'raster' layer. I find examples of CustomLayerInterface, but I do not know in case of using raster tile.
Any help would be appreciated.
Sorry for my poor English. Thank you.

Comment: You'd probably need to create your own custom layer implementation of the raster layer and handle all the drawing code yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I have been developping using Leaflet and I will try to use Mapbox GL JS. But I do not have enought knowldge on Mapbox GL JS.
If I get a sample script for it, I will easily understand the way to customize.

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-layer/ is a great example of using custom layers in Mapbox GL JS.

Comment: The sample of CustomLayerInterface I found is exactly that.
I tried it and understood but I cannot find how to spread raster tiles just like MapBox GL JS style.
I am now reading source code of MapBox GL JS... it is difficult.